# Is it possible to assign a hotkey to rename a title in foobar2000?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, rename, tags, foobar2000

I am trying to map the F2 key in the normal playlist view to the following action: Open the properties of the selected track, move to the title field and enable editing. Right now I am doing this by pressing `alt + enter`, then `arrow down` (twice) and finally `f2`. I can't find an option in the hotkeys dialog to assign that specific course of action. Is there some way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: are you trying to change file name or mp3 tag?

Comment: I am trying to change the title tag, not the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DefaultUI use [ColumnsUI](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_ui_columns). This alternative playlist viewer has [Inline metafield editing](http://yuo.be/wiki/columns_ui:playlist_view) via <kbd>F2</kbd> which acts like Windows Explorer renaming.

[image]

Set up your columns (e.g artist and title) and [bind a meta field](http://yuo.be/wiki/columns_ui:config:playlist_view:columns) to each column. Once you pressed F2 you can cycle trough columns via <kbd>TAB</kbd>

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks for the suggestion. Although I'd like to know if this is achievable with the default UI.